# How to set height and width of downloading image in javascript PHP

Tags: javascript

I am working with php and javascript,I have button "Download" and on button click
i am downloding "screenshot" (as html inside "wrapper div"),But i want to set "height" and "width" of
downloding screenshot,How can i do this ? Here is my code

```
<div id="wrapper">
<h3>Lorem Ipsum dummy text</h3>
</div>


 <button onclick="generate()">Download</button> 


<script>
(function(exports) {
    function urlsToAbsolute(nodeList) {
        if (!nodeList.length) {
            return [];
        }
        var attrName = 'href';
        if (nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLImageElement.prototype || nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLScriptElement.prototype) {
            attrName = 'src';
        }
        nodeList = [].map.call(nodeList, function(el, i) {
            var attr = el.getAttribute(attrName);
            if (!attr) {
                return;
            }
            var absURL = /^(https?|data):/i.test(attr);
            if (absURL) {
                return el;
            } else {
                return el;
            }
        });
        return nodeList;
    }

    function screenshotPage() {
        var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
        html2canvas(wrapper, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                    saveAs(blob, 'myScreenshot.png');
                });
            }
        });
    }

    function addOnPageLoad_() {
        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
            var scrollX = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollX || 0;
            var scrollY = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollY || 0;
            window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
        });
    }

    function generate() {
        screenshotPage();
    }
    exports.screenshotPage = screenshotPage;
    exports.generate = generate;
})(window);
</script>
```

Comment: I’m seeing canvas and JavaScript, but no PHP or jQuery, are they a part of your actual problem? If so, please post the code using those technologies as it relates to the problem, otherwise please update your tags. Bitmap images, such as PNG and JPEG, have intrinsic dimensions. Please explain what “setting the width and height” means.

Comment: @ChrisHaas: Noted and updated "Tags"

Comment: Thanks for updating. What do you mean by height and width? On what do you want to set this?